# ML.NET vs Azure ML Studio

Tags: azure, azure-machine-learning-service, ml.net

I have to do a sales prediction and I'm evaluation using a ML.NET solution hosted in a virtual machine(in Azure) vs using Azure ML Studio. The data may change once or twice per month. Which solutions should I choose? Also, for my use case, pricing might be a factor.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short:
If you are building a .NET application and want to integrate ML, use ML.NET.
If you don't do .NET, use Azure ML.
Docs are helpful here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/data-guide/technology-choices/data-science-and-machine-learning

Comment: From a pricing perspective, for my use case, do you have any insights on which might be cheaper?

Comment: Well, Azure ML is a cloud service where you pay for the compute power that you "burn" whereas ML.NET is a Toolkit for .net that you can run anywhere. You don't pay anything for using ML.NET itself.